# Trends in Externalizing Identity from Applications

Tags: openid, geneva-framework, cardspace, xacml

Stackoverlow decided to use OpenID probably due to its simplicity while others believe that Information Cards (e.g. cardspace) is a better strategy in that it is backed by major industry vendors and is known to be more secure.

Are there libraries that a developer can drop into a Java web application that will easily support both?

Comment: I understand the value proposition of each but would like to understand more about how to support both at the same time...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Information Cards and OpenID are not mutually exclusive, and can be used to great effect in a complimentary fashion, as demonstrated in [this short video by Kim Cameron](http://www.identityblog.com/wp-content/images/2008/02/OpenID/Normal/OpenIDPhish.html) from his [Identity Weblog](http://www.identityblog.com/).

Comment: I am aware of the fact that they can be used together. I use signon.com to access stackoverflow.  Attempting to get insight from other than the creators of technology.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&ct=res&cd=4&url=http%3A%2F%2Fidunno.org%2Fpresentations%2Fwebdd%2FAn%2520Introduction%2520to%2520CardSpace.ppt&ei=sF4NSqCUIYfGMvKC1aYG&rct=j&q=cardspace+java&usg=AFQjCNEI4BcXGZUDSgshjg3utluN34QS2g) is a presentation that compares the two. There is even a link at the end for Java implementations of CardSpace. However, it seems to be from a CardSpace point of view, so be careful of bias.

Comment: I am aware of the technologies used, but want to understand more around why more sites aren't using them.